# Finding the maximum of rows

Tags: matlab, max

Say that we have the following matrix:

```
I=[3 4; 5 3; 6 3; 7 4];
```

If we want to find the maximum value in each row, we can do the following:

```
m=max(I,[],2);
```

For `m`, how do we read this? How is the statement interpreted? What should we do if we want to find the maxim of the `columns`?

Thanks.

Comment: Simply `max(I)` gives the maximum over columns

Answer (score 5):

First off, familiarize yourself with the following: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html.

`max` has two versions. One that finds the maximum elements in one array, and one that compares two arrays of the same size. The first version must be passed either 1 or 3 arguments to distinguish it from the second version, which always takes two arguments.

In your specific case, the arguments to `max` are interpreted as follows:

1. 'I' is a 2D array for which you would like to find the maxima.
2. The empty array `[]` is required by the function to differentiate the version of `max` you are using.
3. The last argument specifies the dimension along which you want the maxima to be returned: `2` means maxima of each row, `1` would find the maximum for each column.

The return value will be a vector of the same length as your other dimension: if you find the maxima along each row, the vector will have as many elements as you have rows.